# Euler function using COS and SIN

Tags: complex-numbers

I already asked a similar question but now I have source code and I still don't get it. I am trying to understand the Euler formula :$$ e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$$

Since I am not a mathematician but a programmer, I looked at the source code of the .NET framework for the EXP function. From what I understand, this function should be $e^{ix}$. Here is the code:

```
public static Complex Exp(Complex value) // The complex number raised to e 

{
    Double temp_factor = Math.Exp(value.m_real);
    Double result_re = temp_factor * Math.Cos(value.m_imaginary);
    Double result_im = temp_factor * Math.Sin(value.m_imaginary);
    return (new Complex(result_re, result_im));
}
```

If the formula $e^{ix}$ should replace $\cos(x) + i\sin(x)$, why does the EXP function still uses COS and SIN?

Comment: Read it as $\,e^{a+ib} = e^a \cdot e^{ib}= e^a \cos(b) + i \,e^a \sin(b)\,$.

Comment: The Euler formula doesn't want to replace anything, you can understand it even as the *definition* of the exponential function for purely imaginary argument. Why would anybody replace existing functionality (implemented in the *hardware* of the floating point unit of contemporary processors) by a program for complex numbers (not supported by hardware of existing processors)?

Comment: So does that mean that the formula from the left is in fact calculated using the formula from the right? Like a function f(x) = 2x ? I thought that it was an equivalence like cos(x) = sin(x+90).